# Array list items replace old ones instead of being added

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I have the problem that instead of being added, the new `items` on my `ArrayList` (which are created in another Activity and sent  to the Main Activity via an Intent) replace the old ones so I always have only one item shown. This is my `Main Activity`:

```
public class AssetsOverview extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
protected List<Transaction> myTransactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_assets_overview);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fabplus = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabAdd);
    fabplus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(AssetsOverview.this, AddMoneyTransaction.class));
        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fabminus = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabRemove);
    fabminus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(AssetsOverview.this, RemoveMoneyTransaction.class));
        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fabhint = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabHint);
    fabhint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(AssetsOverview.this, HintMoneyTransaction.class));
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //transaction list

    populateTransactionList();
    populateListView();

    //set a value to the balance variable

    float startBalance = 0;

    //calculate and set current (actual) balance

    TextView balance_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.balance_view);
    balance_view.setText(startBalance + " $");

}

//populated transaction list

protected void populateTransactionList() {
    myTransactions.add(new Transaction(78,98,"halo"));
}

//populated list view

private void populateListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<Transaction> adapter = new LastTransactionsListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.last_transactions_listView);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class LastTransactionsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Transaction>{
    public LastTransactionsListAdapter(){
        super(AssetsOverview.this, R.layout.transaction_list_view, myTransactions);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        //make sure there is a view to work with (may null)
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null){
        itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.transaction_list_view, parent, false);
        }

        if(getIntent().getExtras() !=null) {

            Intent depositIntent = getIntent();
            Transaction deposit = depositIntent.getParcelableExtra("data");
            assert false;
            Float newVal = deposit.getValue();
            String newDes = deposit.getDescription();
            Integer newDat = deposit.getTransaction_Date();

            //find a transaction to work with

            Transaction currentTransaction = myTransactions.get(position);

            // fill the view:
            //    value
            TextView valueView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.transactionValueView);
            valueView.setText(newVal + "$");

            //    date
            TextView dateView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.transactionDateView);
            dateView.setText(newDat + "");

            //    description
            TextView descriptionView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.transactionDesciptionView);
            descriptionView.setText(newDes);
        }
        return itemView;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.assets_overview, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

And here is my `Activity` where I add the new items:

```
public class AddMoneyTransaction extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button addDepositButton;
EditText depositInput, depositInputDate, depositInputNote;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_money_transaction);

    //setup the Button and EditText

    addDepositButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addDepositButton);
    depositInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.depositInput);
    depositInputDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.depositInputDate);
    depositInputNote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.depositInputNote);

    //get the onClickListener

    addDepositButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    Intent depositIntent = new Intent(AddMoneyTransaction.this, AssetsOverview.class);
    Transaction deposit = new Transaction(100, 16, "random comment");
    deposit.setValue(Float.parseFloat(depositInput.getText().toString()));
    deposit.setTransaction_Date(Integer.parseInt(depositInputDate.getText().toString()));
    deposit.setDescription(depositInputNote.getText().toString());

    depositIntent.putExtra("data",deposit);
    startActivity(depositIntent);
}
```

I kow its a lot of code but after hours of troubleshooting I could not figure out what the correct solution is. Oh and I did not find anything on the google...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `getView()` method. What your code is doing is the following:

You create the adapter using a reference to a list with one item (`new Transaction(78,98,"halo")`), which means that the `getView()` method will be called only for the position 0.

Then, inside the `getView()`, you get the transaction object from the intent and change the item values for the new values. There is no mention of items being added.

You need to change the following things:

1. Read the intent in `AssetOverview.onCreate()` instead of inside the adapter
2. Since your list should survive between activities, you may save it in a singleton instance and just add a new item when you receive it from the intent
3. Call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` every time the list gets updated
4. You may get the transaction in the getView() method by calling `Transaction current = getItem(position)`
5. If you're using a singleton, remember to set it to null in your `AssetOverview.onDestroy()` method, to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: Thank you I will try this as soon as possile.

Comment: If I try to add the notifyDatasetChanged it cannot resolve the method (it is in the populateListView method)