# populate transaction list with every new intent

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

So I have something like this:

```
protected void populateTransactionList() {
    myTransactions.add(new Transaction(78,98,"hello"));
}
```

Now I want this to happen only if there is a new intent from another activity (that carries some data to replace the (78,98,"hello")). Since I am not very experienced with coding could somebody please help we with this little problem?
(The Intent is not my problem but the population of the ArrayList. I did not find a thread that could help me with this.) 
thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Comment: @JozefDochan no I've seen this one but that is not my problem. I want to add an Item to the ArrayList every time there is a new Intent

Comment: if you are creating another activity and then awaiting result  try using [startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Answer (score -1):

You want to override the activity method [`onNewIntent(Intent intent)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent))

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // call intent.getExtra(..) method to get your stored transaction value(s)

    // call myTransactions.add(...) with the values from the intent
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but it did not work. Nothing was added to the ArrayList.

Comment: If you've tried it can you post the code that you tried? Things to check: How are you putting the values in the intent? how are you attempting to access them?

Comment: This is how I am accessing the Intent. I know that it is sent properly because I did use it elsewhere...                                                         `protected void onNewIntent(Intent depositIntent) {
        super.onNewIntent(depositIntent);

        Transaction deposit = depositIntent.getParcelableExtra("data");
        Float newVal = deposit.getValue();
        String newDes = deposit.getDescription();
        Integer newDat = deposit.getTransaction_Date();

        myTransactions.add(new Transaction(newVal,newDat,newDes));

    }`

Comment: have you set a breakpoint and checked the values with the debugger to see if it was stored in the intent correctly and if your parcelable implementation is working correctly?

Comment: are you sure that you aren't re-initializing the array list anywhere after you have added the new values? Can you post the full code?

Comment: here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41666805/array-list-items-replace-old-ones-instead-of-being-added (I posted this question again because maybe it was a bit too specific in the linked question)

Comment: If you're using the base transaction class it isn't parcelable, so I think the problem is writing it to the intent and reading it back properly.

I would extend it and implement parcelable. The source can be found here:

https://developer.android.com/samples/AsymmetricFingerprintDialog/src/com.example.android.asymmetricfingerprintdialog/server/Transaction.html

Comment: You could also store each of the transaction values as individual extras, fetch them individually in onNewIntent, and then create your new intent there.